# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request

Tags: web-services, security, header, apache-axis

I am working in axis2-1.6.2, rampart-1.6.2 & apache Tomcat 7. Based on this link http://thilinamb.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/saml-2-0-token-profile-support-in-rampart-1-5/#comment-118, I have created the webservice and deployed to Tomcat server. Then I run the client code from my IDE(Netbeans), I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:79)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:114)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 11 more
```

anyone have an idea, please let me know?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your client doesn't include the security information needed. Is the client set up to use the SAML authentication?

Comment: Yes I think so. Because I can see the request token look like this "<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="29f2d66be71c77f6f72ef92d8545eed620bcb1e657823b06" IssueInstant="2013-02-05T02:09:52.515Z" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer>SAMPLE_STS</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><ds:Reference URI="#29f2d66be71c77f6...